# iOS rotate screen lost all fonts and styles

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a problem that, I know how to fix.

In AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
CSLoginController *loginController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:CSLoginControllerIdentifier];

[navigationController pushViewController:loginController animated:NO];
```

I set Login Controller.

My first problem is that this method:

```
self.appNameLabel.font = [APPEARANCE fontMediumWithSize:self.appNameLabel.font.pointSize];
```

don' t work in `viewDidLoad`, but working in `viewDidAppear`, 
second problem is: I can rotate my device, the label have got system font, my font disappear.

I have got storyboard with initial controller.

My loginController is in storyboard, too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try NUI? 
Or do everything as there? using categories https://github.com/MaksimVialykh/nui

1. Add category UILabel (with font param)
2. In method

   ```
   - (void)didMoveToWindow
   ```

   Apply your customization.

This is works great!